# fresh windows installation doesn't work as expected

Tags: windows-7, laptop, 64-bit, crash, sony-vaio

I have a [VAIO laptop](http://www.sony-asia.com/support/product/VPCS116FG) which has not been working as expected recently.

At first, I had the Blue Screen of Death coming after some minutes of working with Windows and a crash dump. I used to ignore it since it restarted windows whenever it happened and it wasn't too frequent: about two-three times a week.

[image]

After a month the computer became very slow and I couldn't work with it any more.

I re-installed Windows 7 Home Premium again, but after a day it became as slow as before. I tried installing windows 8, but it was the same. I finally installed Windows 7 Home Premium while formatting and deleting all partitions during installation.

Now after four or five days, again there are problems and today the Blue Screen showed up again. chkdsk found 0 bad sectors. I also tried system start-up repair the second day after installation.

I don't know what is wrong with my laptop that a fresh installation cannot fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: Here is the link to sony's support http://esupport.sony.com

Comment: Unless you post the crash dump and the BSOD error message we won't be able to help.  Your HDD is unlikely the problem if you have been able install several different operating systems without a problem.  The best advice is you stop reinstalling operating systems until you figure out the cause of the crashes your experiencing.

Comment: Use [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to recreate your blue screens and post them here (only one if they all have the same STOP info). Post also screen-captures of the analysis of the dump by BlueScreenView that shows which driver caused the crash.

Comment: That's good, but we also need images like [this one](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview.gif) and like [this one](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview2.gif).

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks, I'm not sure where should I get the other image from.

Comment: bug check code "0x0000007A" is key. Google that code and see what's going on...

Comment: From BlueScreenView : while a .dmp file is selected, use the menu Options / Lower Pane Mode. These are just display option. It might be simpler if you posted a .dmp file, which are normally found in `C:\Windows\MiniDump`.

Comment: It's difficult to follow the question with these images, I think it'd better to link to them or something.

Comment: The images are useful - leave them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STOP code 0x0000007A with the third parameter 0xC0000185 means STATUS_IO_DEVICE_ERROR,
which is defined as
"improper termination or defective cabling on SCSI devices or that two devices are trying to use the same IRQ".

This means that the problem is more probably hardware than software,
but it can still be a problem with a new device driver introduced by Windows Update.
This can be verified by trying to roll back the driver associated with the disk.

The advice given is normally to open up your computer and check for problems in the disk cabling and the SCSI termination. The disk cable might need reseating or replacement. Question: Do you have SCSI disks?

If you have no experience with checking these kinds of disk problems,
better get professional help.
You can point them to the disk(s) as the most likely problem area,
but of course the problem can be elsewhere.
Unfortunately this kind of problem can have lots of causes, such as
virus/malware, drivers, memory and disk corruption. And there
can even be combinations of those. Added possible causes
are hardware errors such as damaged motherboard or other hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error:

**Bug Check 0x7A: KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> The KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR bug check has a value of 0x0000007A. **This
>   bug check indicates that the requested page of kernel data from the
>   paging file could not be read into memory.**

Parameter 2 shows the error status (usually an I/O status code). In your case it is 0xc0000185, which means there is an IO error with your hard drive.

```
C:\Users\André>err 0xc0000185
# for hex 0xc0000185 / decimal -1073741435
  STATUS_IO_DEVICE_ERROR                                         ntstatus.h
# The I/O device reported an I/O error.
# 1 matches found for "0xc0000185"
```

So run a diag tool from your HDD manufacture to check for HDD errors.

Answer (score 0):

Run Hardware Diagnostics. Nine times outa ten, If you re-install your OS and still get the BSODs it's hardware. In this case it sounds like it's a HDD. Replace it, they're a dime a dozen.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit how to run memory diagnostic? I tried to download and install [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) but to  no avail.

Comment: were you able to boot to the memtest disc?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: You need to get both your HDDs and RAM tested.

Comment: Right, but how? I need a step by step guide.

Comment: Download Memtest, Burn ISO, Boot to ISO

Comment: @Gigili you have a HDD issue, no RAM issue.

Comment: @magicandre1981: How did you find out I have HDD issues? What should I do about it?

Comment: replace the disk. it's cheap and easy. hard drives are not expensive. get a cheap $50 disk, install it, and reinstall windows.

Comment: @Gigili I looked at the STOP and the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if a Linux live disk will work for a while, if even that crashes it may be hardware. if it doesn't crash boot windows in safe mode and roll back any and all recently updated drivers but whatever you do do-not install windows 10 on the device until you can get windows 7 (avoid using 8 if possible) to work as is has much more hardware support. odds are its not your hard drive because you would experience slow buggy crashes not and copious loss of data, frequent corruption and all out hard-drive failure. so see what devices you can roll back safely. also see if running it in safe mode prevents the problem. also keep in mind that the NTOSKRNL.exe does have known bugs with memory leaking in windows 10 if you fix it and decide to uupgrade

Comment: Just a point of information, this question is 2 years old and has an accepted answer.